# Enable wifi wlan adapter Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-20.04

I have a Raspberry 3 Model B which has a BCM43438 wireless LAN and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) on board and recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Thanks in advance for looking and let me know if Ubuntu 20.04 on RPI3 does not support wifi at this time.

I've read a few posts saying look for the /etc/network/interfaces file but I have no such file on the computer:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/network$ ls -laFioh
total 32K
767 drwxr-xr-x   6 root 4.0K Dec  3 16:18 ./
 59 drwxr-xr-x 115 root  12K May 24 00:54 ../
768 drwxr-xr-x   2 root 4.0K May 23 22:57 if-down.d/
770 drwxr-xr-x   2 root 4.0K May 24 00:20 if-post-down.d/
772 drwxr-xr-x   2 root 4.0K May 24 00:20 if-pre-up.d/
775 drwxr-xr-x   2 root 4.0K May 23 23:08 if-up.d/
```

When querying the hardware I get the following:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.10.243  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.10.255
        inet6 2600:8802:5700:4e9::17ef  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9e:342b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:8802:5700:4e9:ba27:ebff:fe9e:342b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:9e:34:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 12903  bytes 3076937 (3.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1448  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4753  bytes 1548962 (1.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 360  bytes 27732 (27.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 360  bytes 27732 (27.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Here is (edited for post length) dmesg:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/network/if-up.d$ ifconfig -a | dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-1011-raspi (buildd@bos02-arm64-055) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)) #11-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 8 07:43:33 UTC 2020 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-1011.11-raspi 5.4.34)
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] efi: Getting EFI parameters from FDT:
[    0.000000] efi: UEFI not found.
[    0.000000] Reserved memory: created CMA memory pool at 0x0000000037400000, size 64 MiB
[    0.000000] OF: reserved mem: initialized node linux,cma, compatible id shared-dma-pool
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 242688
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 3792 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   DMA zone: 242688 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 32 pages/cpu s92120 r8192 d30760 u131072
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s92120 r8192 d30760 u131072 alloc=32*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3
[    0.000000] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU0
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 845719
[    0.000000] CPU features: kernel page table isolation forced ON by KASLR
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: Kernel page table isolation (KPTI)
[    0.000000] CPU features: detected: ARM erratum 843419
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 238896
[    0.000000] Kernel command line:  coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:9E:34:2B vc_mem.mem_base=0x3ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc quiet splash
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 8, 1048576 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 829544K/970752K available (11772K kernel code, 1234K rwdata, 4232K rodata, 6144K init, 1070K bss, 75672K reserved, 65536K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] random: get_random_u64 called from kmem_cache_open+0x38/0x3e0 with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 38918 entries in 153 pages
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 64, nr_irqs: 64, preallocated irqs: 0
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000006] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000259] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000286] printk: console [tty1] enabled
[    0.000346] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=76800)
[    0.000365] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000675] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.000740] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.000870] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.001143] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.001174] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.001272] *** VALIDATE tmpfs ***
[    0.002123] *** VALIDATE proc ***
[    0.002726] Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.002810] *** VALIDATE cgroup1 ***
[    0.002824] *** VALIDATE cgroup2 ***
[    0.004609] ASID allocator initialised with 32768 entries
[    0.004842] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.007381] EFI services will not be available.
[    0.008566] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.009828] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU1
[    0.009895] CPU1: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000001 [0x410fd034]
[    0.011639] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU2
[    0.011687] CPU2: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000002 [0x410fd034]
[    0.013379] Detected VIPT I-cache on CPU3
[    0.013424] CPU3: Booted secondary processor 0x0000000003 [0x410fd034]
[    0.013911] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.013923] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated.
[    0.013936] CPU features: detected: 32-bit EL0 Support
[    0.013949] CPU features: detected: CRC32 instructions
[    0.020184] CPU features: emulated: Privileged Access Never (PAN) using TTBR0_EL1 switching
[    0.020196] CPU: All CPU(s) started at EL2
[    0.020299] alternatives: patching kernel code
[    0.022694] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.037343] Enabled cp15_barrier support
[    0.037374] Enabled setend support
[    0.038045] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.038073] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.041727] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.042605] DMI not present or invalid.
[    0.043595] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.051797] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic allocations
[    0.051833] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.052166] audit: type=2000 audit(0.048:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.053055] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.053107] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.053801] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.054258] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.057099] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.072352] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2020-02-12 12:38, variant start
[    0.076366] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 53a54c770c493957d99bf49762dfabc4eee00e45
[    0.141228] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.144632] iommu: Default domain type: Translated
[    0.146755] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.147103] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.147383] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.147442] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.147573] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.148025] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.148035] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.148061] PTP clock support registered
[    0.148431] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.150257] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.150269] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.150277] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.150375] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.151661] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.273752] *** VALIDATE bpf ***
[    0.274312] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.274440] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.274605] *** VALIDATE ramfs ***
[    0.275419] AppArmor: AppArmor Filesystem Enabled
[    0.275758] simple-framebuffer 3eaf0000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0x3eaf0000, 0x10a800 bytes, mapped to 0x(____ptrval____)
[    0.275776] simple-framebuffer 3eaf0000.framebuffer: format=a8r8g8b8, mode=656x416x32, linelength=2624
[    0.276413] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 82x26
[    0.281022] simple-framebuffer 3eaf0000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
[    0.295933] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.295977] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.296094] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.296289] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.296548] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.296601] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.296928] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.296963] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    0.296984] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.297351] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
[    1.310272] Freeing initrd memory: 28784K
[    1.312081] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_cortex_a53 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    1.312256] kvm [1]: IPA Size Limit: 40bits
[    1.313553] kvm [1]: Hyp mode initialized successfully
[    1.317894] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.317956] Key type blacklist registered
[    1.318274] workingset: timestamp_bits=46 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    1.328818] zbud: loaded
[    1.331807] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
[    1.333293] fuse: init (API version 7.31)
[    1.333464] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[    1.333481] *** VALIDATE fuse ***
[    1.373876] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.373892] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.373983] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 243)
[    1.374368] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.380355] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: FB found 1 display(s)
[    1.385548] bcm2708_fb soc:fb: Registered framebuffer for display 0, size 656x416
[    1.469838] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    1.472384] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.473038] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.474044] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x3f200000
[    1.474439] cacheinfo: Unable to detect cache hierarchy for CPU 0
[    1.966042] loop: module loaded
[    1.969071] spi-bcm2835 3f204000.spi: could not get clk: -517
[    1.971483] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.971531] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.972035] PPP generic driver version 2.4.2
[    1.972336] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.972411] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.972453] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.972482] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.972547] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.972582] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.972634] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.972831] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    2.186906] Core Release: 2.80a
[    2.186920] Setting default values for core params
[    2.186949] Finished setting default values for core params
[    2.400133] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    2.400144] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.400153] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.400165] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    2.400184] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    2.401079] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1072: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = ffff800010556000 dma = 0x00000000f7510000 len=9024
[    2.401109] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    2.401120] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    2.401162] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:496: MPHI regs_base at ffff80001007d000
[    2.401231] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.401266] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.401332] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 9, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.401384] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.401393] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.401774] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    2.401790] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.401804] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.401818] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1011-raspi dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.401831] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    2.402670] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.402738] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.403580] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    2.403590] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    2.403599] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    2.403614] Module dwc_common_port init
[    2.404408] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.404996] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.408010] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    2.408297] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[    2.408713] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.41.0-ioctl (2019-09-16) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
[    2.408963] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    2.411208] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.411213] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.411577] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    2.411939] sdhost-bcm2835 3f202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    2.412049] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.414057] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.414194] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.414991] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (____ptrval____)
[    2.418173] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    2.418914] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.460979] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.461071] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.461278] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.461876] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.461932] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    2.471617] Loaded X.509 cert 'Build time autogenerated kernel key: 2b0c993598f9ffc45348fe691c2d17c0cab9b970'
[    2.471798] zswap: loaded using pool lzo/zbud
[    2.472116] Key type ._fscrypt registered
[    2.472121] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    2.501207] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    2.607939] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.693627] random: fast init done
[    2.710992] Key type big_key registered
[    2.762921] Key type encrypted registered
[    2.762951] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled
[    2.762984] ima: No TPM chip found, activating TPM-bypass!
[    2.763014] ima: Allocated hash algorithm: sha1
[    2.763042] ima: No architecture policies found
[    2.772506] printk: console [ttyS0] disabled
[    2.772557] 3f215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 61, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
[    2.778456] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    2.779024] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    2.782201] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.782211] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    2.799679] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.808101] sdhost: log_buf @ (____ptrval____) (ebcc4000)
[    2.829576] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    2.829585] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.830092] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.830179] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.856496] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.858071] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    2.858506] of_cfs_init
[    2.858622] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.869359] Freeing unused kernel memory: 6144K
[    2.877944] Checked W+X mappings: passed, no W+X pages found
[    2.877955] Run /init as init process
[    2.917209] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.920196] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[    2.921176] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD32G 29.3 GiB (quirks 0x80000000)
[    2.924046]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.969634] random: systemd-udevd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.123722] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.144196] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
[    3.144210] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.147118] smsc95xx v1.0.6
[    3.207434] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:9e:34:2b
[    3.830336] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.940418] random: crng init done
[    3.940425] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[    4.055733] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
[    8.055717] mmc1: error -110 whilst initialising SDIO card
[    8.134713] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    9.259806] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    9.353840] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    9.465573] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    9.466660] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
[    9.560839] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <ubuntu>.
[   10.939306] systemd[1]: /lib/systemd/system/dbus.socket:5: ListenStream= references a path below legacy directory /var/run/, updating /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket → /run/dbus/system_bus_socket; please update the unit file accordingly.
[   11.322186] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[   11.341802] systemd[1]: Listening on Network Service Netlink Socket.
[   11.536895] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   11.556519] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[   11.564954] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[   11.567305] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[   11.571435] systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[   11.573773] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[   11.593020] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
[   11.593308] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
[   11.606500] systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   11.625818] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
[   11.634244] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[   11.708756] systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
[   11.716806] systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
[   11.745901] systemd[1]: Finished Create System Users.
[   11.765450] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[   11.853725] systemd[1]: Finished Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[   11.872599] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[   11.975918] systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
[   11.989425] systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
[   12.130267] systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
[   12.295740] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   12.331312] systemd-journald[699]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[   12.338368] systemd-journald[699]: File /var/log/journal/3514f49f5a9540e08799a3236ffb69fb/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[   15.447028] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.447847] vc_sm_cma: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.449312] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[   15.449326] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[   15.450053] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[   15.483330] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   15.543700] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   15.624819] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.647282] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   18.803843] alua: device handler registered
[   18.809440] emc: device handler registered
[   18.816655] rdac: device handler registered
[   21.052015] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.787:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1122 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.052047] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.787:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=1122 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.071424] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.803:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=1120 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.075311] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.807:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=1121 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.080322] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.815:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1126 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.080352] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.815:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1126 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.120841] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.855:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1127 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.133913] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.867:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1123 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.133957] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.867:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=1123 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   21.133976] audit: type=1400 audit(1585761833.867:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1123 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   29.389895] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   30.921666] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[ 1503.818761] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[ 1503.897593] st: Version 20160209, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
[ 1548.482170] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[ 2134.819517] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
```

And here is hwinfo --short:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/network/if-up.d$ sudo hwinfo --short
cpu:
                       CPU
                       CPU
                       CPU
                       CPU
network:
  eth0                 Standard Microsystems SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
network interface:
  eth0                 Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
disk:
  /dev/mmcblk0         Disk
partition:
  /dev/mmcblk0p1       Partition
  /dev/mmcblk0p2       Partition
usb controller:
                       ARM USB controller
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Standard Microsystems SMC9514 Hub
memory:
                       Main Memory
unknown:
                       PS/2 Controller
```

Answer (score 0):

flow this steps to config:

1 install network tools

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

2 start wifi

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

3 edit wifi config

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

4 apply config

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off

sudo netplan --debug try
sudo netplan --debug generate
sudo netplan --debug apply
```